# With Knockout.JS how to attach an event handler using custom binding handler

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

My binding handler adds a hyperlink to a list item tag. I would like to know how to attach click event to the hyperlink through the binding handler. The click event should call a function within the view model.

You can see code in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h8ejqx5L/2/).

So my question is: How to attach an event handler to call showSectionName from the view model? Maybe using something like `ko.bindingHandlers.click(...)`?

```js
$(function () {
    ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapHyperlink = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var elt = "<a href='#'>" + viewModel.name + "</a>";
            $(element).append(elt);
        }
    };

    var Section = function (id, name) {
        var self = this;

        self.id = id,
        self.name = name
    };

    self.showSectionName = function (data) {
        alert("You clicked the section " + data.name);
    }

    function viewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.Sections = ko.observableArray([
            new Section(1, "Section 1"),
            new Section(2, "Section 2"),
            new Section(3, "Section 3")
        ])
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div style="width:200px">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-bind="foreach:Sections">
        <li role="presentation" data-bind="bootstrapHyperlink: {click: showSectionName($data)}">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You're correct, it's not in the ViewModel but it's in the script block: showSectionName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html) for `ko.utils.registerEventHandler`

But it also looks like this might be a good use for [ko.components](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html).

Comment: Thank you - I'm having a look at your links now.

Comment: I checked the RPN link and added: `ko.bindingHandlers.click.init(element, valueAccessor);` to the handler but its executing all the links on loading. After that it works as expected. Check [link]https://jsfiddle.net/h8ejqx5L/4/

Comment: This is actually the worst of the provided alternatives. But good luck, @user1309226.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for advanced techniques like custom binding handlers for your problem.

You ought not to build HTML with jQuery when you use knockout. Knockout builds all your HTML for you. Consider this simple example:

```js
function Section(id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
Section.prototype.showSectionName = function () {
    alert("You clicked '" + this.name + "'");
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.sections = ko.observableArray([
        new Section(1, "Section 1"),
        new Section(2, "Section 2"),
        new Section(3, "Section 3")
    ]);
}

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:200px">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-bind="foreach: sections">
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#" data-bind="text: name, click: showSectionName"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note that using the `prototype` only works for regular functions, not for knockout's `computed` values.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, it's just I didn't want to complicate my question. The need for the custom binding handler is because I need to have a span inside a hyperlink and they're both data bound. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h8ejqx5L/8/ The number 42 is hard-coded but it should be bound to the view model as well. I'm trying to use ko and bootstrap together.

Comment: Can you explain why you think you need a custom binding handler that builds HTML? You can build a span inside a hyperlink just fine with knockout, what's not right with that? Have you ready through my code sample?

Comment: Compare https://jsfiddle.net/h8ejqx5L/9/, that's my code from above with a minimal change to the view. I don't see your problem. ;)

Comment: Thanks for you time. See the following code does not produce the result I expect from '<a data-bind="attr:{href:'#'}, text: name, click:showSectionName"><span class="badge" data-bound="text:id"></span></a>'. check again fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h8ejqx5L/8/

Comment: You cannot use the `text` binding inside an element that already has the `text` binding. Use a second `<span>` inside the `<a>` instead.

Comment: Please check your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h8ejqx5L/10/ I included the boostrap libraries. It does show the section id in the span! Perhaps something I've done wrong. It should show Section 1   10. The number 10 is the badge.

Comment: No, I won't debug that sample. I just said you can't use the text binding inside the text binding, I don't know why but it seems you are not listening to me.

Comment: @Tomalak cant agree more on this  `no need for advanced techniques` +1 . cheers

Comment: @user1309226 check here https://jsfiddle.net/h8ejqx5L/13/ . as you are using `text` binding on `<a>` & also on `<span>` which is inside `a` tag outer text binding overriding the inner text is what @tomalak trying to convey .

Comment: @supercool thanks for the contribution. However, what I want to see is Section and the badge inside the boostrap pill - such as Section 1   10, and then next row Section 2  20. The entire li tag is clickable. No hardcoding of text 'Section'. What you showed in your fiddle was just the badge.

Comment: @user: For example: https://jsfiddle.net/h8ejqx5L/15/. But [as I said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562846/with-knockout-js-how-to-attach-an-event-handler-using-custom-binding-handler/31563645?noredirect=1#comment51084442_31563645), you can just as well use separate `<span>`: https://jsfiddle.net/h8ejqx5L/16/. I gave you all the hints yesterday already, you simply chose not to think them through. That's a bit sad.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

I hope this is more like what you were after: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h8ejqx5L/11/)

```
<div style="width:200px">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-bind="foreach:Sections">
        <li role="presentation" data-bind="bootstrapHyperlink: name"></li>
    </ul>
</div>

$(function () {
    ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapHyperlink = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
            var elt = "<a href='#'>" + value + "<span class='badge'></span></a>";
            $(element).append(elt);

            $(element).on('click', function () {
                alert($(this).text());
            });
        }
    }

    Section = function (id, name) {

        var self = this;

        self.id = id,
        self.name = name
    };

    function viewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.Sections = ko.observableArray(
        [
        new Section(1, "Section 1"),
        new Section(2, "Section 2"),
        new Section(3, "Section 3")]);

        self.showSectionName = function (data) {
            alert("You clicked the section " + data.name);
        }
    }
    var vm = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I think I may have to use the custom binding handler in this situation. This is to be used with Bootstrap.js to form a hyperlink including a span using the badge widget. Something like: <a href="#">Section <span class="badge">42</span></a> Number 42 (just an example) will be data bound.

Comment: @user1309226 This is using your custom bindingHandler.

Comment: Thank you for your effort but we're not there yet. But it is important that when I click on the hyperlink it calls the showSectionName function. In fact showSectionName should be inside the viewModel.

Comment: @user1309226 Ok I've amended the answer with the function inside the viewmodel and it does call the function like you wanted.

Comment: I added the function to the viewmodel.